# Beginner multi-join question

Tags: sql, mysql, join

There are 3 tables for a small trading system; **USERS**, **ITEMS** and **TRADES**, the trades themselves are held in table TRADES (logically enough), as:

```
column     type
========== =====
seller_id  int
buyer_id   int
item_id    int
quantity   int
cost       int
currency   int
```

I want to display pending trades, using a 3-way join to map IDs to names in tables USER and ITEM. So far I've got:

```
SELECT
    users.name AS seller,
    items.id AS item_id,
    items.name AS item,
    trades.item_id AS trade_id,
    trades.quantity AS quantity,
    trades.cost AS cost,
    trades.currency AS currency 
FROM
(trades INNER JOIN users ON trades.seller_id = users.id) 
INNER JOIN items ON trades.item_id = items.id 
WHERE trades.buyer_id = xxx
```

The first join works fine, but as soon as I pass the result to the second it fails; returns zero data. I'm braced for it being a real noobie problem (in fact I'm hoping it is, easy to fix = good) but I can't see it (probably because I am in fact a noob at these things).

Comment: The only reason I could see this not working is if the item_id did not exist within the items table.  With INNER JOINS you're saying that there must exist at least one item in the table with that id.

Comment: @user628935 - Try to use a left join first and see if you get the right data.  Also is there really a buyer_id with the value xxx ?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
      users.name AS seller, 
      items.id AS item_id, 
      items.name AS item, 
      trades.item_id AS trade_id, 
      trades.quantity AS quantity, 
      trades.cost AS cost, 
      trades.currency AS currency   
FROM 
      trades
LEFT JOIN 
      users 
ON 
      trades.seller_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN 
      items 
ON 
      trades.item_id = items.id
WHERE trades.buyer_id = xxx
```

Comment: I used left joins just in case you are missing data in a table, but you know your data more then I do.  So use what you know.

Comment: Jon thank you, that is spot on.  Curses, I thought I had my head around this as well. Hey ho, back to the textbooks. But thank you.

Comment: @user628935 - No problem please don't forget to accept an answer so the thread is basically closed.

Answer (score 1):

I think trades_id needs to be trades.item_id

I also advise you to use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, only use INNER JOIN when you want to trigger a error if there's no match. When you use LEFT JOIN it always returns data, also when there's no match in the second table. See: http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: You are entirely right Ray and I apologise for the bug. However it has opened up something I didn't know and need to know, so selfishly that is useful for me.  And thank you.